# Trying to loop non-contiguous rows in a range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write something that will loop through a range of non-contiguous rows in a table, and change column data in each row ... for example, ClearContents. The range will be dynamic, and the rows I want to loop through will all be "Selected."

I tried the following, but it stopped after the first row. I am pretty sure the problem is that the next row is non-contiguous to the first row:

```
 For Each b In a.Rows
 mainTasks.DataBodyRange(Range("mainTasks[Status]").Column).ClearContents
 Next b
```

Then I had the bright idea to write something that works only the "selected" column cells. I tried using `If ... .Value = Selected` and that didn't work.

Am I trying to do something that Excel 2016 VBA can't do? That is, loop through non-contiguous rows in a range? I've been researching and tried several other things that don't work. Can you tell me if I am going down the wrong rabbit hole?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to simplfy your code in the comments for testing purpose, but the following code should help,

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim myrange As Range
For x = 1 To 30
   If (mainTasks.Cells(x, 2) = "completed" Or mainTasks.Cells(x, 2) = "Dismissed") And mainTasks.Cells(x, 3) <> "" Then
      If myrange Is Nothing Then
         Set myrange = mainTasks.Cells(x, 2)
      Else
         Set myrange = Union(myrange, mainTasks.Cells(x, 2))
      End If
    End If
Next x
myrange.ClearContents
```

I tried it out and it works Ok given the way I set it up.  Hope it helps!

You will also have to add the code to copy the data, I am clearing the contents in this one, given that was your original question

Comment: Super. Just one quick question. Does "For x = 1 to 30" assume that there are 30 rows in the table? What would be the syntax for the end of the table without a number of rows? I know I've seen it ... i'm just having a brain freeze.

Comment: Sure it would be something like "Worksheets("mainTasks").UsedRange.Rows.Count" if i remember correctly

Comment: Dman, THANK YOU! I tried your simplified code and got an error, so I just plugged in my old code block and it worked! Now I'm going to go back and troubleshoot the simplified code ... I probably made some change that broke it. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem :)  if you could mark this as solved that would be great

Comment: Dman, sorry for the delayed response but I think I was in error when I said it worked ... I must have seen the "Status" column clear and mistakenly thought it cleared only the "myrange" rows, as I needed it to do. Instead, it cleared the whole Status column. As an alternative I changed the code to create the new rows in the same table ... is there any way I can declare these new rows to be an object, range, or area, and clear the Status only from that new range of rows? I've tried to do this but I can't seem to get the syntax right.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any variables in your loop.

It will just the clear the one column repeatedly in the loop. You need to somehow reference b in the loop to have a different outcome in each loop.

Answer (score 0):

This works too (i think)

```
Dim selectedRange As Range

Set selectedRange = Application.Selection

For Each Row In selectedRange.Rows
    Debug.Print Row.Address
Next Row
```

Comment: Dman and Michael, thank you. Dman, I tried your code and it stops after the first row, same as the original. I think the problem, again, is that the selected rows in the range are not contiguous. Would it work somehow to say, OK, go ahead and look through the whole column but only perform this action on the rows that are selected? An If Then statement?
 What is the correct syntax to say that a row is selected?

Comment: You shouldn't have to loop through the entire column, the above code works for me OK, (I selected rows 4,11,24 and 31 only in column C) and the debug window printed ($C$4, $C$11, $C$24 and $C$31)  How are you selecting the "rows" are you holding down CTRL and selecting them? or some other method?

Comment: Hello Dman, the rows are selected in a prior section of the macro. My project is a "To Do" list in an Excel table. I am trying to solve the problem of updating recurring tasks.  When a task is marked as "Completed" under column [Status], my macro copies it to a table on another sheet, so I can maintain a record of the tasks. Then the macro goes back to the original table and re-selects the range of completed tasks, for the purpose of clearing [Status] and updating [Start]. The completed tasks will be in different locations every time, so I won't be able to identify them by address.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes a difference, now when you select the cells, could you post the part of the code that selects them?

Comment: Tasks2.Activate
        Dim a As Range, b As Range
        Set a = myRange
        Dim myNewRows As Variant
        
            For Each b In a.Rows
                Set myNewRows = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("recurrCompl").ListRows.Add
                b.Copy
                myNewRows.Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            Next

    Tasks.Activate
    a.Select

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this and I'm having trouble formatting the code in a comment box. I'll see if I can make it more readable.

Comment: **For x = 1 To mainTasks.Range.Rows.Count
        If mainTasks.DataBodyRange(x, Range("mainTasks[Status]").Column) = "Completed" _
        Or mainTasks.DataBodyRange(x, Range("mainTasks[Status]").Column) = "Dismissed" _
        And mainTasks.DataBodyRange(x, Range("mainTasks[Recurr]").Column) <> "" Then
            If myRange Is Nothing Then
                Set myRange = mainTasks.ListRows(x).Range
            Else
                Set myRange = Union(myRange, mainTasks.ListRows(x).Range)
            End If
        End If**  'Dman, the results of this code are selected for copying.

Comment: Hi B. Wildered, Sorry for the long delay, do you still need help with this issue?

Comment: Hello Dman! I am still having problems, but I think I will keep working on it and perhaps ask another question if needed. Thanks for checking back! I'm sure the problem is me and not your solution! I'm pretty new at this.

Comment: Anytime, let us know if you need any further help.